# What is a good book for continue studying analysis after Ross?

Tags: reference-request

I have just finished Ross' Elementary Analysis, I'm just wondering what would be a good "next in the line" book to read, and perhaps after them as well?  Can somebody give me an idea of the "trail" of books that I should be reading?

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try principles of mathematical analysis by Walter Rudin. You can find it online. By the way, here is a supplement with comments on the proofs in Rudin's Book:

http://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/ug.hndts/m104_Rudin_exs.pdf

Hope this helps